# Pass data between two controllers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner on rails, so I guess it is an easy question, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I have two controllers: Exercises and PersonalWorkouts.

I want to choose all of the Exercises, pick a few of them, 
and for each exercise picked I need to create a PersonalWorkout with this exersice_id. 
So there should be numerous PersonalWorkouts created with one click.

Calling exercises directly from the PersonalWorkouts controller didn't work, @exercises was nil.

```
class PersonalWorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def make_plan
    @exercises = Exercise.all
  end
```

How should I do it right?

Comment: Post the error message you're getting. Where was `@exercises` nil?

Comment: Got to say I don't like this at all. Delegate this/these to an other class, then new one up and call it from either controller as required.

Comment: @JKen13579 on the make_plan view, I put: `<%= @exercises %>`.
and I get  `#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Exercise:0x2af9e70>`

Comment: That isn't a `nil` error. You're just displaying all the exercise at once. You need to loop through them and display them one-by-one.

Comment: @JKen13579 you are right, I was stuck for hours on this simple thing, thank you :)

Comment: No problem! I moved everything from the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've established in the comments, you had `<%= @exercises %>` in your view and seeing `#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Exercise:0x2af9e70>` in your browser.

In order to display `@exercices`, you need to loop through them and display them one-by-one.

```
<% @exercises.find_each do |exercise| %>
  <!-- Do something with each exercise -->
<% end %>
```